# Do you need to release xib UI elements that aren't IBOutlets?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, xib

If I have a xib file with, say, a UIButton element, but I do not create an IBOutlet to it, will it be released automatically? Or do I need to create outlets to all UI elements, and release them, even if I don't necessarily need the outlet for other purposes?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to create outlets to every UI element. All memory management should be handled automatically.